# How to fix double line equation going on right align

Tags: equations, align

Here's my latex code:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \text{Susceptibility Score (one location)} = \sum_{\substack{w \in \text{RF Importances} \\ \theta \in \text{Static Features}}}{w_f \theta_f} = \\ 
        w_{\text{infra}}\theta_{\text{infra}} + w_{\text{slope}}\theta_{\text{slope}} + w_{\text{forest}}\theta_{\text{forest}} + w_{\text{litho}}\theta_{\text{litho}}
    \end{aligned}
    \label{eq:sus-formula}
\end{equation}
```

It produces this equation
[image]

You can see that the second line of the equation is crammed to the right. How can I make it left aligned?

Comment: you have no alignment point  (`&`)  in the alignment so you just have the left hand side of each row which is right aligned to the missing right hand side, it also seems to be too wide for the column but as you have provided no test example hard to comment on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `split` environment, provide `&` alignment points, and create an extra line break.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}% or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % "vn" is short for "variable name"
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:sus-formula}
\begin{split}
&\text{Susceptibility Score (one location)} \\
&\quad= \sum_{\substack{w \in \text{RF Importances} \\ 
                       \theta \in \text{Static Features}}} 
                       w_{\!f} \theta_{\!f} \\
&\quad= w_{\vn{infra}}\theta_{\vn{infra}} 
      + w_{\vn{slope}}\theta_{\vn{slope}} 
      + w_{\vn{forest}}\theta_{\vn{forest}} 
      + w_{\vn{litho}}\theta_{\vn{litho}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect! What does the \! do?

Comment: @ShreyJoshi - The `\!` directives insert "negative thinspace", to reduce the distance between `w` and `\theta` and the `f` subscript terms.